# Android Material You - Inconsistency in themes

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, material-you

```
<!--    Has purple statusBar and white navigationBar-->
<style name="Base.Theme.Appp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar"/>
<!--    Has transparent statusBar and transparent navigationBar-->
<style name="Theme.Appp" parent="Base.Theme.Appp" />
<!--    Has purple statusBar and white navigationBar-->
<style name="Theme.Appp.Another" parent="Base.Theme.Appp"/>
<!--    Has purple statusBar and white navigationBar-->
<style name="Theme.ApppAnother" parent="Base.Theme.Appp"/>
<!--    Has purple statusBar and white navigationBar-->
<style name="Theme.Appp.AnotherOne" parent="Theme.Appp"/>
```

So, I got a bunch of themes that represent different colors. I'm trying to have the user be able to pick the main color they want. I also want the window to have transparent bars. The problem is that only Theme.Appp has transparent systembars. What is the reason of this inconsistency?

(I've done this on a fresh instance of a Material 3 Basic Activity template that Android Studio made.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="Theme.MonetCompatWithM3" parent="Base.Theme.MonetCompatWithM3">
    <!-- Transparent system bars for edge-to-edge. -->
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">?attr/isLightTheme</item>
</style>
```

It's because the theme was overridden in v29.